# Username/Pass request during WinService installation

Tags: c#, installation, windows-services, installshield-le

I have done a test Win service to make sure I have the Installer project (which is the part of that project and is set to InstallShield Limited by default) works fine.

I've searched for the correct manual and did the same as it was suggested:

Pls, see the WinService Installation class definition:
[image: Screen of the Installer Class]
Then I tried both ways

1) [image: Way#1]

2) [image: Way#2]
Then I successfully build the Installation project and get the setup package..

As you can see everything is set to be installed under the Local user..
But each time I run the installation pask it asks for credentials.. 
[image: Creadential request dialog]

My question is: how to avoid that dialog during installation?

Comment: "As you can see..." - no, I'm not seeing it. I'm seeing a set of screenshots that don't tell me much. Rather than posting images, give us a *narrative* instead. Start from the "New Project" dialog in VS and work from there.

Comment: No, text and reproducible steps are preferred. Have you considered the fact that you question, as asked, is almost inaccessible to those who use assisstive technologies to access this site? Prefer a question that can be understood by those with access only to the text (which includes search engines)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the solution by myself.

The start point should be: To make yourself sure that the **service is installable manually** using InstallUtil.

In my case I mistakenly named ServiceName in AfterInstall event, when engaged Service Controller.. missed letter "1"

```
private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
    using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName))
    {
        sc.Start();
    }
}
```

After that I changed the settings in InstallShield Project..
1) I dropped the added service at screen Way#1
2) Add InstallClass as it shown on Way#2

The request of the credential was because inside the service itself, I missed setting LocalSystem for Property Account of Service Process Installer in the Design Mode.

So, now it works..